# Como hacer una división con dos consultas de tablas distintas en mysql?

Tags: mysql

Hola quisiera saber si fuera posible hacer esta división entre estas consultas de diferentes tablas ya he probado de distintas maneras y no he logrado tener éxito

esta es la primera

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(b.Fecha_ini) AS Mes, sum(b.Hora_parada ) AS Horas
FROM orden_trabajo as b
INNER JOIn solicitud_mante a on a.Id_soli = b.Id_soli
where a.Tipo_mante = 'Correctivo Inmediato'
GROUP by year(b.Fecha_ini), month(b.Fecha_ini)
```

y esta es la otra

```
SELECT SUM(case when Paro_mante = 0 then 1 else Paro_mante end) AS Paro, MONTHNAME(Fproceso) AS Mes
from proceso 
GROUP BY YEAR(Fproceso), MONTH(Fproceso)
```

Lo que quiero dividir las horas entre los paros

Answer (score 1):

Usa las consultas como si fueran 'tablas' haciendo un JOIN entre ellas.

```
SELECT T1.Horas / T2.Paros
FROM (
      SELECT MONTHNAME(b.Fecha_ini) AS Mes, sum(b.Hora_parada ) AS Horas
      FROM orden_trabajo as b
      INNER JOIn solicitud_mante a on a.Id_soli = b.Id_soli
      where a.Tipo_mante = 'Correctivo Inmediato'
      GROUP by year(b.Fecha_ini), month(b.Fecha_ini)
     ) AS T1
JOIN (
       SELECT SUM(case when Paro_mante = 0 then 1 else Paro_mante end) AS Paro, MONTHNAME(Fproceso) AS Mes
       from proceso 
       GROUP BY YEAR(Fproceso), MONTH(Fproceso)
     ) AS T2
ON T1.Mes = T2.Mes
```

Answer (score 1):

La idea es básicamente la misma de Jdev, usar subconsultas, pero en este caso, solo sobre las horas de paro.

```
SELECT  YEAR(b.Fecha_ini)       AS Anio,
        MONTHNAME(b.Fecha_ini)  AS Mes, 
        SUM(b.Hora_parada)      AS Horas,
        IFNULL(p.Paro,0)        AS Paro,
        SUM(b.Hora_parada) / CASE IFNULL(p.Paro,0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE IFNULL(p.Paro,0) END AS Ratio
    FROM orden_trabajo as b
    INNER JOIn solicitud_mante a 
        ON a.Id_soli = b.Id_soli
    -- Subconsulta de "Paros"
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT YEAR(Fproceso) AS anio, 
                      MONTH(Fproceso)  AS mes,
                      SUM(case when Paro_mante = 0 then 1 else Paro_mante end) AS Paro
                      FROM proceso 
                      GROUP BY YEAR(Fproceso), MONTH(Fproceso)
        ) p
        ON MONTH(b.Fecha_ini) = p.mes
        AND YEAR(b.Fecha_ini) = p.anio
    WHERE a.Tipo_mante = 'Correctivo Inmediato'
    GROUP by 
        YEAR(b.Fecha_ini), 
        MONTH(b.Fecha_ini),
        IFNULL(p.Paro,0)
```

Como podrás apreciar, hacemos una subconsulta que en definitiva funciona como cualquier tabla, con la sumatoria de `Paro_mante`  por mes y año. Luego simplemente hacemos un `LEFT JOIN` con el resto de las tablas por el año y el mes. No olvides siempre que te toque hacer una división, verificar el divisor para evitarte problemas de división por 0.